# How can I animate a ScaleTransform from multiple triggers?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

First of all: I am just trying to get started with WPF and play around with it a little, so things may not be fully optimal and I an happy for any suggested improvement.

I am having following Style and Template for my buttons and try to scale them larger on mouse hover and smaller for click, which does nearly work:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Name="ButtonGrid"  Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                          Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" ClipToBounds="True" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">

                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform></ScaleTransform>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>

                        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
                            <Canvas Name="svg2" Width="100" Height="100">
                                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="-322.04954" Y="-476.16966"/>
                                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <Path Name="path2985" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="#FFDB2325" StrokeMiterLimit="4">
                                    <Path.Data>
                                        <PathGeometry Figures="m 166.96292 92.089554 c 0 43.240226 -35.05313 78.293346 -78.293349 78.293346 -43.240223 0 -78.29335 -35.05312 -78.29335 -78.293346 0 -43.240224 35.053127 -78.29335 78.29335 -78.29335 43.240219 0 78.293349 35.053126 78.293349 78.29335 z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                    </Path.Data>
                                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                                        <MatrixTransform Matrix="0.6305699 0 0 0.6305699 316.13718 468.10076"/>
                                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                                </Path>
                                <Path Name="path2987" Fill="#FFDB2325">
                                    <Path.Data>
                                        <PathGeometry Figures="m 145.26718 89.259674 a 61.314068 61.314068 0 1 1 -122.628138 0 61.314068 61.314068 0 1 1 122.628138 0 z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                                    </Path.Data>
                                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                                        <MatrixTransform Matrix="0.63076923 0 0 0.63076923 319.0945 469.8674"/>
                                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                                </Path>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Viewbox>

                        <!-- Present Content (text) of the button. -->
                        <DockPanel Name="myContentPresenterDockPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="myContentPresenter" Margin="20" 
      Content="{TemplateBinding  Content}" 
      TextBlock.Foreground="White" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                            To="1.08"  Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                                            To="1.08" Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                            To="1.00"  Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                                            To="1.00" Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                            To="0.95"  Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                                            To="0.95" Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                            To="1.00"  Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                                            To="1.00" Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The problem is, that when I click a button, the MouseOver Trigger either is not executed anymore or the scale does not work. So the button is not scaled up on MouseOver anymore.

Many thanks for an hints :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the IsMouseOver Trigger to MultiTrigger and Move IsPressed Trigger above the IsMouseOver multi trigger like as shown below.

```
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                        To="0.95"  Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                                        To="0.95" Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                        To="1.08"  Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                                        To="1.08" Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard >
                                    <Storyboard >
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                        To="1.08"  Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                                        To="1.08" Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard >
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                        To="1.00"  Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                                        To="1.00" Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiTrigger>                        
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: I am sorry for the long delay, but I wanted to say thank you for that answer. It works great. I had tested it some time ago and just forgot to thank you...